# Load pickled object on different machines

Tags: python, numpy, arm, pickle, cpu-architecture

I've dumped a classifier of scikit-learn via pickle. My plan is to deploy this classifier on a different machine (armv7l). But when I want to load this object I get this error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'SIZE_t' but got 'long long'
```

I expect that there are problems because of the different architectures and the C-Implementation of numpy.

Is there a way to pickle an object for an different CPU architecture?

Comment: That may sound obvious, but have you checked Python and Scikit-learn are the same version on both systems?

Comment: When you dump the classifier via pickle did it already have a method of serializing it or did you write your own?

Comment: @Chachmu I did it as recommended by the documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)

Comment: @Balzola Yes, I have checked the Python, numpy and scikit-learn version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumping on one architecture and loading on another is not supported. For further information see: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7891